# Best way to dynamically add variables to SQL queries if the variables change

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

So I have a situation in which I am dynamically using certain variables in my code depending on the values of those variables. So for example:

```
select 
    TP.TreatmentID,
    TP.ProductID,
    TP.OptimizationGroupID,
    MIN(TP.CalculatedFromText) AS CalculatedFromText,
    TP.TreatmentOrdinal,
    TP.SamplingRandomNumber,
    TP.CurrencyCode'+
    case when @Origin !='' then ' ,TP.Origin' else '' end +
    case when @Destination != '' then ' ,TP.Destination' else '' end +
    case when @fareclass='Y' THEN ' ,Fareclass' else '' end +
    case when @ispriorbooking='Y' THEN ' ,IsPriorBooking' else '' end +' 
INTO ##CalculatedFromText
FROM ##CalculatedFromTextTmp TP
GROUP BY  
    TP.TreatmentID,
    TP.ProductID, 
    TP.OptimizationGroupID,
    TP.TreatmentOrdinal,
    TP.SamplingRandomNumber,    
    TP.CurrencyCode '+
    case when @Origin !='' THEN ' ,TP.Origin' else '' end +
    case when @Destination !='' THEN ' ,TP.Origin' else '' end +
    case when @fareclass='Y' THEN ' ,TP.Fareclass' else '' end +
    case when @ispriorbooking='Y' THEN ' ,TP.IsPriorBooking' else ''
end
```

This is part of my code. WHen I had these 4 variables to add dynamically, it was easy. But now the goal would be to able to have a table with any number of variables to add to these queries.

So basically my table I want the variables from will have a primarykey variable along with the values for all the variables I want to join on the primarykey

The number of variables will change.

I was thinking of just joining in the table, but not sure if thatd work because eventually i am doing max and sum calculations on variables I include in a group by query, but if I join to table it will necessarily include the primarykey variable which cant be used in the group clause. Thus I was adding variables dynamically instead of joining on a table.

Is there a good way of using all the variables in a table in a dynamic way.

I am more looking on ideas for a solution instead of troubleshooting.

Table specifics:
Table I want to be able to dynamically use:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(
primarykey varchar(100),
variable1 VARCHAR(100),
variable2 VARCHAR(100),
variable3 date
)
insert into @t values
('1','A','C','2015-01-01'),
('2','A','C','2015-02-01')
```

the goal of the overall body of code is calculating sales results for each group of variables provided by this table. In this example, variable1, variable2 and variable3 would be used in the code in select and group by statements.

Comment: It might be possible to do what you're trying, but it seems like you outside of t-sql's sweet spot.  It might be better to solve this in another language.

Comment: Showing aggregates based on dynamic parameters might be better achieved in SSAS. If you could build something to do this (i.e. dynamic SQL) you would have a few issues: 1. protecting against SQL Injection; 2. anticipating functionality of future variables that don't exist now. 3; performance